# Pasar contenido de una tabla a otra con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

necesito pasar todo el contenido de una tabla mysql a otra, con un controlador en laravel, pongo el siguiente codigo,

```
  public function store(Request $request)
 {
   
  $consulta=DB::raw("INSERT INTO warehouses (war_mat_id, war_mst_id, war_ser_id) 
   SELECT (temp_mat_id, temp_mst_id, temp_ser_id FROM temporal120210107)");

}
```

no me muestra error pero tampoco hace nada, si ejecuto esa sentencia directo en la consola de mysql, funciona sin problemas la inserción de los registros, pero no se como hacerlo en el controlador.
intente hacerlo así, pero tampoco me funciono.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
 $consulta=DB::table('warehouses')->insert([DB::table('temporal120210107')
 ->select('temp_mat_id', 'temp_mst_id', 'temp_ser_id')->get()]);
 }
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el uso del método `raw` por el método `insert` del *facade* `DB` de esta forma:

```
$consulta=DB::insert("INSERT INTO warehouses (war_mat_id, war_mst_id, war_ser_id) 
SELECT (temp_mat_id, temp_mst_id, temp_ser_id FROM temporal120210107)");
```

**Referencia**

- [Aquí puedes leer más](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-insert-statement)